# JQuery return value from child window to parent

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog

first I have a list of records that has an edit button for each row (Please see below image 1 parent window). Once I clicked the edit button, a pop-up will appear which shows the Answer field in the pop-up window (Please see image 2 child window). In the pop-up window, there is a text area which handles the answer value, from here the user can add/delete a value. once the user clicked the save button, the values should be save in the database and reflects the modified value of the answer field on the particular row that was choosen to edit in the parent window.

Here is my code so far, I didn't implement a Controller yet for this because I don't know how to, I don't know if the controller can be called here for saving the data in to the dadabase.

I am new to MVC, I am hoping that there is someone who can help and understand my problem.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost] 
       public ActionResult Sample(string answers, string question, string controlid, string eventid)
       {

           return View("CustomizedQuestion");
       }
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".editButton").live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $title = $(this).attr("title");
                var $answers = $(this).attr("answers");
                var $controlid = $(this).attr("id");
                dropdownlist($controlid, $title, $answers);
            });

 function dropdownlist(controlid, title, answers, eventid) {

var $answersreplaced = answers.replace(/\,/g, "&nbsp;\r");

var $deleteDialog = $('<div><textarea id="answerlist"  rows="10" cols="50">' + $answersreplaced + '</textarea><div><div style="font-size:9px">(To change back to an open answer field, delete all choices above and save)</div>');

$deleteDialog.dialog({

    resizable: false,

    height: 280,

    width: 350,

    title: title + " - Edit Choices",

    modal: true,

    buttons: {

        "Save": function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Sample")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { answers: $('#answerlist').val(),
                       question: title,
                       controlid: controlid,
                       eventid: eventid
                     },

                success: function (resp) {

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },

                error: function () {
                    alert('there was a problem saving the new answers, please try again');
                   }
            });

        },

        Cancel: function () {

            $(this).dialog("close");

        }

    }

});

};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can add an ajax call in the dialog's `save` callback, which would send the new values to the server?

Comment: Can you please send me some sample codes on how to do it. I'll appreciate it a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

As requested by comment:

```
$(".editButton").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $title = $(this).attr("title");
        var $answers = $(this).attr("answers");
        var $controlid = $(this).attr("id");
        var questionID = $(this).attr('questionID');
        dropdownlist(this, questionID, $controlid, $title, $answers);
    });

function dropdownlist(el, questionID, controlid, title, answers) {
    var $answersreplaced = answers.replace( /\,/g , "&nbsp;\r");
    var $deleteDialog = $('<div><textarea id="answerlist"  rows="10" cols="50">' + $answersreplaced + '</textarea><div><div style="font-size:9px">(To change back to an open answer field, delete all choices above and save)</div>');
    $deleteDialog
        .dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 280,
            width: 350,
            title: title + " - Edit Choices",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    var dialog = $(this);
                    $.ajax(function()
                    {
                        url : 'controller-path',
                        type : 'POST',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data : 
                        {
                            Answers : $("#answerlist").val(),
                            QuestionID : questionID
                        },
                        success : function(resp)
                        {
                            $(dialog).dialog("close");
                            var newanswers = $("#answerlist").val();
                            modifyanswers(controlid,newanswers);
                        },
                        error : function()
                        {
                            alert('there was a problem saving the new answers, please try again');
                        }
                    });
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
};
```

In addition to this, you would need to add an attribute named `questionID` which stores the ID of the row the answers relate to.

On a separate note, I would avoid using attributes in this way. You can store the title in title, as that is a valid attribute, although answers and in my example questionID are not valid attributes and as a result, will fail HTML validation.

You could/should look at storing them in another way.

Comment: thanks, but I have a question, why does the error in ajax is always raising?error : function() 
                        { 
                            alert('there was a problem saving the new answers, please try again'); 
                        }

Comment: It depends on how you are implementing it... Have you just copied and pasted the code I've given you and not done anything else? Have you setup your controller to receive the request and insert the new answers? If you have Chrome or Firefox (install firebug), press F12 to look at the Ajax requests and the reason why it's throwing an error.

Comment: I  created a controller like this: [HttpPost] 
       public ActionResult Sample(string answers, string question, string controlid, string eventid)
       {

           return View("CustomizedQuestion");
       }

Comment: please see the updated one.Actually it calls the controller successfully but after the excution of the controller it goes back to the javascript function and the execute the error function, the controller above is the sample that I've implemented. What is the problem with the controller?

Comment: As above, you need to use Chrome or FireBug to see what error is being returned. Without seeing the page in action or your code, it's hard to tell what the cause is.

Comment: here is the error "attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope" it seems it is very generic error

Comment: @Galvin, I solved the error already but my problem is, how the changes made reflects to the parent page?